# In Django: Can I set logging level highest than CRITICAL?

Tags: python, django, logging

I have a project in Django 1.5 and a have logging handlers for debug, info and error.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console':{
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
        'file_debug':{
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, '..','logs','DEBUG.log'),
            'when':'midnight',
            'interval':1,
            'backupCount': 4,
            'formatter':'simple',
            'filters':['require_debug_true']
        },
        'file_info':{
            'level':'INFO',
            'class':'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, '..','logs','INFO.log'),
            'when':'midnight',
            'interval':1,
            'backupCount': 4,
            'formatter':'simple',
        },
        'file_error':{
            'level':'ERROR',
            'class':'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, '..','logs','ERROR.log'),
            'when':'midnight',
            'interval':1,
            'backupCount': 4,
            'formatter':'simple',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request':{
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
}
```

However I would like to have a log file that only contains specific stuff, I don't want any of the errors printed in it. I thought that using CRITICAL level may solve my problem, but since the information on my log is only for reporting info, it may become handful to have a generic level higher than CRITICAL, like:

```
        'file_report':{
            'level':'REPORT',
            'class':'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, '..','logs','REPORT.log'),
            'when':'midnight',
            'interval':1,
            'backupCount': 4,
            'formatter':'simple',
        },
```

What would be the best practice for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure a custom logger and send messages to it. For example, assuming your package is called `foo`:

```
LOGGING = {
    ...
    'handlers': {
        ...
        'file_report': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, '..', 'logs', 'REPORT.log'),
            'when':'midnight',
            'interval': 1,
            'backupCount': 4,
            'formatter':'simple',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'foo.report': {
            'handlers': ['file_report'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
    },
}
```

Then in your application code:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('foo.report').info('something something')
```